# javascript library to convert web page to pdf

Tags: pdf-generation

Is there any client-side library that can convert a web page to a PDF document? I have used jspdf but the generated pdf does not retain the formatted html (like  tags should be boldface in the PDF).

Answer (score 5):

Very simple if your page is *not having any sensitive data*
Just Do this:

```
<a href="http://pdfcrowd.com/url_to_pdf/">Save this page to a PDF</a>
```

---

OR

Download [this](http://www.pdfmachine.com/pdfMachineSDK_1.9.9.zip) tool.

And you can invoke it on any event like:

```
<script>


  function generatePDF(){} 

  var conv = new ActiveXObject("pdfServMachine.converter");
  conv.convert("http://www.google.com", "c:\\google.pdf", false);
  WScript.Echo("finished conversion");
 }

 </script>
 <body onload="generatePDF()">
 </body>
```

```
var conv = new ActiveXObject("pdfServMachine.converter");
conv.convert("http://www.google.com", "c:\\google.pdf", false);
WScript.Echo("finished conversion");
```

---

OR

For more information
http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf
http://itextpdf.com/
http://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

---

Comment: My table does have sensitive information .
Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @SudiptaRoy If you got answer for your question. You can accept the answer.. Not only on this question but all of your questions.

Comment: This is a helpful yet not a satisfying answer. This only works if the data isn't sensitive.

Comment: @Peter: Yes.. That I'd already mentioned.. glad that you found it bit helpful atleast..

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be pointing fingers. Its just frustrating that there isn't a real, properly working solution for this yet... 10 years after pdf was invented.

Comment: Is there anyway to take an existing page and saving the content as PDF?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: You can do that by using JavaScript, look for [jsPDF](http://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)