# Using JavaScript to create a PDF file of the current web page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want the user to click a 'View PDF' or 'Download PDF' button on the current web page, which would do nothing but execute JavaScript code that generates a PDF out the current page's look.

I tried jspdf but it did not work out at all, so what are my options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782642/how-to-convert-html-page-to-pdf-using-javascript), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975694/how-to-convert-an-html-page-to-pdf-file-using-javascript-are-there-any-js-fil), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491657/javascript-library-to-convert-web-page-to-pdf), or [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152470/how-to-convert-an-html-page-to-pdf-using-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your other option is to use http://parall.ax/products/jspdf#

but believe me you will end up creating your `PDF` file in the server side

like `itextSharp` for `C#.NET` or `VB.NET` or what ever is equivalent for `PHP`

Comment: True, I ended up using WeasyPrint.